# Why is the Home Controller's Index action not being hit when program starts up?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, url-routing

When I start my ASP.NET MVC application up, it does not hit the `HomeController`'s `Index` action, but when I explicitly type the URL `Home/Index`, it works as expected.

Here is how the end point is set up in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            // endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            // Blazor
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        });
```

Comment: Your MVC application?  Not a blazor application ?

Comment: @QingGuo Kind of embarrassing , but my work has mixed two frameworks, that is why the  endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host"); and endpoints.MapBlazorHub();

Comment: Is your Index.razor has `@page "/"` ?

Comment: @QingGuo it is a index.cshtml file, and the HomeController's Index method should be returning the view. When I explicitly type Home or Home/Index it works as expected, but on startup the default route does not seem to work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the below code in your _Host.cshtml

```
@page "/"
```

into

```
@page ""
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the demo, do you mind explaining why this behavior happens?

Comment: @NishantSharma  You are welcome:) , that will set `/home/index` to  the '_host` , it's a mistake, sorrry, please see my updated answer.